# Test with QuoteLineItem insert fails in some sandboxes but not all with REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING UnitPrice error

Tags: apex, failing-tests

I have a test class with setup method which creates an account, opportunity, quote. Then the test method retrieves the quote and sets up a QuoteLineItem . The insert of this QuoteLineItem fails with a required field error in my full copy sandbox, but not the original dev sandbox it originated in.

The test method - error occurs on final line after the quoteLineItemTrigger:

```
//get original quote
  Quote theQuote = [SELECT id FROM Quote LIMIT 1];

  Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

  Product2 prod = new Product2(name='Test');
  insert prod;

  PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(Product2Id = prod.Id, pricebook2Id = pricebookId, unitprice=100, isActive=true);
  insert pbe;

  QuoteLineItem qli = new QuoteLineItem(description = 'test', UnitPrice = 100, QuoteId = theQuote.Id , PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id, Quantity = 1, Product2Id = prod.Id );
  insert qli;
```

Error Log:

```
16:18:10.179 (4508462219)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|SMEQuoteLineItemTrigger on QuoteLineItem trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/SMEQuoteLineItemTrigger
16:18:10.179 (4533041934)|DML_END|[331]
16:18:10.179 (4533183632)|VF_PAGE_MESSAGE|Required fields are missing: [UnitPrice]
16:18:10.179 (4533287695)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[331]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [UnitPrice]: [UnitPrice]
16:18:10.179 (4534491507)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[331]|Bytes:135
16:18:10.179 (4534535907)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
16:18:10.179 (4534644526)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [UnitPrice]: [UnitPrice]

Class.SMEQuoteTest.testQuoteHistory: line 331, column 1
16:18:10.179 (4534662270)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [UnitPrice]: [UnitPrice]
```

The code in both sandboxes is identical, other elements cannot be guaranteed as several project teams use this environment enroute to production.

Any thoughts?

Comment: does the fullcopy sandbox have before insert triggers or before-save record-triggered flows that null out the QLI `UnitPrice` ?

Comment: @cropredy Spot on, well done. Looks like another team have added a quoteLinteItem trigger and not narrowed it to their own project. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is the [order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) (before triggers, before save flows can manipulate the values of fields presented to them before the database commit occurs):

Check to see if the fullcopy sandbox includes code that:

- Has a before insert trigger (`SMEQuoteLineItemTrigger`) that nulls out QuoteLineItem.UnitPrice
- Has a before-save record-triggered flow that nulls out QuoteLineItem.UnitPrice